# Rails inverse_of doesn't work with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

Here are my models:

```
class Flight < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :seats, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :flight
end

class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flight, inverse_of: :seats
end
```

It seems that `inverse_of` works well, but when I'm using conditions it doesn't work:

```
f1 = Flight.first
s1 = f1.seats.first
s2 = f1.seats.second
s3 = f1.seats.where(id: 0..1000000).third

s1.flight.equal? s2.flight
=> true
s1.flight.equal? s3.flight
=> false
```

What explains this? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
s1.flight.equal? s2.flight
=> true
```

The above yields true because `s1.flight` and `s2.flight` refer to **the exact same Ruby object**.

```
s1.flight.equal? s3.flight
```

Here, `s1.flight` and `s3.flight` refer to **different Ruby objects**. They both contain the same record data *(including the same `:id` value)*

The problem is you're using Ruby's [`equal?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F) method, when you should be using Rails' `==` or `eql?` comparators.

From **[the Ruby `Object` docs for `==` *(aliased as `eql?` and `equal?`)*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F)**

> Equality — At the Object level, == returns true only if obj and other are the same object. **Typically, this method is overridden in descendant classes to provide class-specific meaning.**

Unfortunately, `equal?` is the variation **not** overridden in `ActiveRecord::Base`. From **[the Rails docs for `==` *(aliased as `eql?`)*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-3D-3D)**:

> Returns true if comparison_object is the same exact object, or comparison_object is of the same type and self has an ID and it is equal to comparison_object.id.

You'll find this has nothing to do with `:inverse_of`. A simple example you can try

```
f1 = Flight.all.first
f2 = Flight.all.first

f1.eql? f2
=> true

f1 == f2
=> true

f1.equal? f2 # Direct Object comparison (skips ActiveRecord::Base)
=> false
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I know equal? tests for "sameness" of objects. I used it in here do demonstrate that this is not the same object. My problem is not testing for equality. The problem is that I need to get back the very same object and not a newly created one. What bothers me is the different behavior of active record when I'm using conditions.

Comment: `The problem is that I need to get back the very same object and not a newly created one.` and the issue is you cannot do that by re-querying the database. Because of this fundamental fact (two identical queries for the same record yield two **different** Ruby objects), your example is flawed. Maybe if you provide a more appropriate example outlining exactly what you're trying to do I can help further.

Comment: OK let me explain. by using `inverse_of` I got to a point where I'm able to get the original Flight object from the Seats that were obtained with `first` and `last`: `s1.flight.equal? s2.flight`. But when I obtained the Seat with a condition (where) I don't get the original flight any longer. The reason I need the original object is that I use it for some simple caching of some computation results and I want to avoid recomputing.

Answer (score 0):

`Inverse_of` option doesn't work with conditions, that's why `s1.flight` and `s3.flight` are not equal - `ActiveRecord` just reloads object from database when you're doing `s3.flight`. This appears to be a documented behaviour, see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23693#issuecomment-184438933